# Flow HTMLElement.querySelector returning an iframe

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Flow doesn't seem to recognize that `querySelector` may return subtypes of `HTMLElement`:

```
var myIframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

function foo(iframe: HTMLIFrameElement): void {
  // I want to do iframe stuff!
}

foo(myIframe);
```

Produces

```
10: foo(myIframe);
        ^ HTMLElement. This type is incompatible with
6: function foo(iframe: HTMLIFrameElement): void {
                        ^ HTMLIFrameElement
```

On https://flowtype.org/try.

Is there any way I can type `myIframe` that will let me use both its `HTMLElement` properties and its `HTMLIFrameElement` properties, apart from typing it as `Object`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flow doesn't know how to parse a selector, which it would need to do to understand what kind of element would be returned. It is able to understand `getElementsByTagName`'s simpler API, though, so [it knows](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/efd42c2cade13f42a9be7522580a108c0e2a20b2/lib/dom.js#L811) that `getElementsByTagName('iframe')` returns `HTMLCollection<HTMLIFrameElement>`.

Using `querySelector`, you'd need to cast it. Something like this:

`var myIframe = ((document.querySelector('iframe'): any): HTMLIFrameElement);`

Comment: Thanks for that, fixed my issue and pointed me to the casting documentation: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/

Comment: Thanks for this. Just so I understand do you have to cast with "any" because it could return a collection of Elements?